Proof of the transitivity of Norm ( Field theory, Hungerford, Algebra, Chapter V, Theorem 7.3. )
I am reading the Hungerford, Algebra, Chapter V, proof of Theorem 7.3 and can't prove the transitivity of norm until now.

Proposition 6.12. Let $F$ be a finite dimensional extension field of $K$ and $N$ a normal extension field of $K$ containing $F$. The number of distinct $K$-monomorphisms $F\to N$ is precisely $[F:K]_s$, the separable degree of $F$ over $K$.


Definition 7.1. Let $F$ be a finite dimensional extension field of $K$ and $\bar{K}$ an algebraic closure of $K$ containing $F$. Let $\sigma_1,\dots, \sigma_r$ be all the distinct $K$-monomorphisms $F\to \bar{K}$ ( c.f. Proposition 6.12 above ). If $u\in F$, the norm of $u$, denoted, $N_K^F(u)$ is the element
$$ N_K^F(u):=(\sigma_1(u)\sigma_2(u) \cdots \sigma_r(u))^{[F:K]_i}$$
( $[F:K]_i$ is the inseparable degree. ) The trace of $u$, denoted $T_K^F(u)$, is the element
$$ T_K^F(u):= [ F: K]_i(\sigma_1(u) + \sigma_2(u) + \cdots +\sigma_r(u)).$$


Theorem 7.3. Let $F$ be a finite dimensional extension field of $K$. Then for all $u,v \in F$ :


(i) $N_K^F(u)N_K^F(v)=N_K^F(uv)$ and $T_K^F(u) + T_K^F(v) = T_K^F(u+v)$ ;


(ii) if $u\in K$, then $N_K^F(u)=u^{[F:K]}$ and $T_K^F(u)=[F:K] u$ ;


(iii) $N_K^F(u)$ and $T_K^F(u)$ are elements of $K$. More precisely, $N_K^F(u)= ((-1)^na_0)^{[F:K(u)]} \in K$ and $T_K^F(u) = - [F : K(u)] a_{n-1} \in K$, where $f=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 \in K[x]$ is the irreducible polynomial of $u$ ;


(iv) if $E$ is the intermediate field, then $$ N_K^E(N_E^F(u))=N_K^F(u)   \ and  \ T_K^E(T_E^F(u))=T_K^F(u).$$

SKETCH OF PROOF OF THEOREM 7.3. (i) and (ii) follow directly from Definition 7.1 above and the facts that $r= [ F:K]_s$ ( $\because$ Proposition 6.12 above ) and $[F:K]_s [F:K]_i=[F:K]$.
(iii) Let $E:= K(u)$. And algebraic closure $\bar{K}$ of $K$ which contains $F$ is also an algebraic closure of $E$. The proof of Lemma 6.11 shows that the distinct $K$-monomorphisms $F \to  \bar{K}$ are precisely the maps $\sigma_k \tau_i ( 1 \le k \le t ; 1 \le j \le r )$, where the $\sigma$'s are all the $K$-automorphisms of $\bar{K}$ whose restrictions to $E$ are distinct and the $\tau$'s are all the distinct $E$-monomorphisms $F\to \bar{K}$. We accept this fact. Thus by proposition 6.12 above, $t= [ E:K]_s$ ( $\because$ By proposition 6.12 above, $tr = [F:K]_s = [F : E]_s [E:K]_s$. And also by using the proposition 6.12, $r= [F:E]_s$ ), whence $n= [E:K]  = [E:K]_s [E:K]_i = t[E:K]_i$ ( C.f. see Ramarks after Definition 6.10 ).
Use (ii) and Corollary 6.13 ( The transitivity of the separable and inseparable degrees ) to show that $N_K^F(u) = ( \prod_{k=1}^{t} \sigma_k(u))^{[F:E][E:K]_i}$ and $T_{K}^F(u) = [F:E] [E:K]_i ( \Sigma_{k=1}^{t}\sigma_k(u))$. We accept this calculation. If needed I will upload proof.
Since $\sigma_i : K(u) \cong K(\sigma_i(u))$, Corollary 1.9 implies that $\sigma_1(u) , \dots , \sigma_t(u)$ are all the distinct roots of $f$ ( $\because$ by the choice, restrictions of $\sigma$'s to $E:=K(u)$ are distinct so each $\sigma_1(u) , \dots , \sigma_t(u)$ are all distinct. And since $t=[E:K]_s$, they are all roots of $f$ by the Corollary 6.14 below ).
Note that

Corollary 6.14. Let $f \in K[x]$ be an irreducible monic polynomial  over a field $K$, $F$ a splitting field of $f$ over $K$ and $u_i$ a root of $f$ in $F$. Then (i) every root of $f$ has multiplicity $[K(u_1) : K]$ , so that in $F[x]$, $$ f= [ (x-u_1) \cdots (x-u_n)]^{[K(u_1) : K]_i},$$ where $u_1 , \dots, u_n$ are all the distinct roots of $f$ and $n= [K(u_1) : K]_s$ ;
(ii) $u_1^{[K(u_1) : K]_i}$ is separable over $K$.

By Corollary 6.14,
$$ f= [ (x-\sigma_1(u))(x-\sigma_2(u)) \cdots ( x- \sigma_t(u))]^{[E:K]_i}
     = [ x^t - ( \Sigma_{k=1}^{t} \sigma_k(u))x^{t-1} + \cdots + ( (-1)^t \prod_{k=1}^{t}\sigma_k(u))]^{[E:K]_i}.$$
If $[E:K]_i =1$, then $n=t$ and the conclusion is immediate. If $[E:K]_i >1$, then $[E:K]_i$ is a positive power of $p = \operatorname{char}K$. ( $\because$ Corollary 6.5 ). It is easy to calculate $a_0$ and to see that $a_{n-1}=0 = T_K^F(u)$ ; use Exercise III.1.11 ( The Freshman's Dream ).
(iv) Use the notation in the first paragraph of the proof of (iii), with $E$ any intermediate field. Apply the appropriate definitions and use Corollary 6.13 ( transitivity of the separable and inseparable degrees ).
I'm trying to follow the bold statement and don't know how to breakthrough.
1. First attempt : Let $E$ be an intermediate field of $F/K$. Note that as in the proof of (iii), we have
$$ N_K^F(u) = (\prod_{k=1}^{t} \sigma_k(u))^{[F:E][E:K]_i} , t= [E:K]_s \tag{1}$$
$$ v:=N_E^F(u) = (\prod_{k=1}^{t'} \sigma'_k(u))^{[F:E'][E' : E]_i} , t'=[E':E]_s  \tag{2}$$
$$ N_K^E(v) = ( \prod_{k=1}^{t''} \sigma''_k(v))^{[E:K'][K':K]_i} , t''=[K':K]_s \tag{3} $$
, where 1) $\sigma$'s are all the $K$-automorphisms of $\bar{K}$ whose restrictions to $E$ are distinct, 2) $\sigma'$'s are all the $E$-automorphims of $\bar{E}= \bar{K}$ whose restriction to $E':=E(u)$ are distinct, 3) $\sigma''$'s are all the $K$-automorphisms of $\bar{K}$ whose restriction to $K':=K(v)$ are distinct. Then after inserting (2) into (3), try to check that it output (1). Sorry for messy notation. After trying to some calculation ( involving transitivity of separable and inseparable degree, multiplicativity of norm etc..) , I reached to conclusion that if
$$ ( (\sigma_1''(\sigma_1'(u)) \cdots \sigma_{t''}''(\sigma_1'(u)) \cdots ( \sigma_1''(\sigma_{t'}'(u)) \cdots \sigma_{t''}''(\sigma_{t'}'(u)) ) = ( \sigma_1(u) \cdots \sigma_t(u) )^{[E' : E]_s / [ E: K']_s} $$
, then we can check our goal.. And it is so brutal force.. Could we adopt a similar approach?
2. Second attempt : Let $v:=N_E^F(u) \in E$. Let $g:= x^{m} + b_{m-1}x^{m-1} _ \cdots + b_0 \in K[x]$ be the irreducible polynomial of $v\in E$. Then by the Theorem 7.3-(iii) above,
$$ N_K^E(N_E^F(u)) = N_K^E (v) = ( (-1)^m b_0 )^{[E: K(v)]}$$
This is same as $N_K^F(u) = ( (-1)^na_0)^{[F:K(u)]}$, where $f:=x^n+ a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 \in K[x]$ be the irreduicible polynomial of $u$. ? In this approach, I don't know what kind of relationship to catch
P.s. imgae of the proof of the Theorem 7.3 is as follows :


How can we follow the underlined statement?
Or is there other simpler route to show the transitivity of norms, following hungerford's intention? Any help would be appreciated.

Please do not use pictures of text.

Let $E$ be an intermediate field. Let $\overline{K}$ is algebraic closure of $K$ containing $F$. Then $\overline{E}= \overline{K}$, since $\overline{K}$ is algebraic over $E$ and $\overline{K}$ is algebraically closed. The proof of lemma $6.11$ shows that the distinct $K$-monomorphisms $F \to  \overline{K}$ are precisely the maps $\sigma_k \tau_j ( 1 \le k \le t ; 1 \le j \le r )$, where the $\sigma$'s are all the $K$-automorphisms of $\overline{K}$ whose restrictions to $E$ are distinct and the $\tau$'s are all the distinct $E$-monomorphisms $F\to \overline{K}=\overline{E}$.
By definition of norm, $$ N_E^F(u)=(\tau_1(u)\cdots \tau_r(u))^{[F:E]_i}= \left(\prod_{j=1}^r \tau_j (u)\right)^{[F:E]_i}.$$
Proof of lemma $6.11$ shows that $\sigma |_E$'s are all the distinct $K$-monomorphisms $E\to \overline{K}$. Note $N_K^E(N_E^F (u))$ make sense because $N_E^F (u)\in E$ by (iii). By definition of norm and corollary $6.13$,
$$\begin{align} N_K^E (N_E^F (u)) &= \left[ \sigma_1\left(N_E^F(u)\right)\cdots \sigma_t \left(N_E^F(u)\right) \right]^{[E:K]_i} \\ &= \left[ \sigma_1\left(\prod_j \tau_j(u)\right)^{[F:E]_i} \cdots \sigma_t \left( \prod_j \tau_j(u) \right)^{[F:E]_i} \right]^{[E:K]_i} \\ &=  \left[ \left( \prod_j \sigma_1 \tau_j(u)\right)^{[F:E]_i} \cdots \left( \prod_j \sigma_t \tau_j(u) \right)^{[F:E]_i} \right]^{[E:K]_i} \\ &= \left( \prod_{i,j} \sigma_i\tau_j (u) \right)^{[F:E]_i[E:K]_i} \\ &= \left( \prod_{i,j} \sigma_i\tau_j (u) \right)^{[F:K]_i} \\ &= N_K^F(u). \end{align}$$
where $1\leq i\leq t$ and $1\leq j\leq r$. Proof is similar for trace.

Thank you! :)  It was more straightforward proof than I thought.

Here is a different way to prove the transitivity of field norms, which is more general and illustrates the underlying linear algebra.
Consider any injective map of commutative rings $A\to B$ such that $B$ is a finite free $A$ module. Then there is a norm map $B^*\to A^*$ given by the determinant of left multiplication by elements of $B$ on itself, viewed as a free $A$ module (choosing an $A$ basis of $B$, this becomes the determinant of a matrix).
If one can show this norm is transitive, then show it agrees with field norms, we are done. Showing it agrees with field norms is easier, for once we know it's transitive, we can check purely inseparable and separable extensions separately. I'll leave that to you, and we see that this transitivity is implied by the following fact:
Given an $mn\times mn$ matrix, such that the $n\times n$ blocks all commute, then taking the determinant "blockwise", then taking the determinant of the new $m\times m$ matrix computes the determinant of the original big matrix.
This is now just a matrix computation though, assume you're over an algebraically closed field (doesn't change the determinant), you can simultaneously upper triangulise the $n\times n$ blocks, as they commute, and compute the result directly in the upper triangular case.
Ruminating on the connection to field norms, this is a nice way to see that field embeddings in some closure are exactly simultaneous eigenvalues of these matrices, separability is diagonalizability, and everything can be understood through linear algebra!

This is Ingraham's result on determinants, and indeed a nice way to see it.

@Chris H :  Thanks. I've reading your answer occasionally and still curios about how apply your proposed argument to prove the transitivity of norm defined as in your answer (by using determinant)-concretely. Anyway I wil try to it. And I still wonder how to accomplish the propose of Hungerford for proof. Upvote +1. Thank you :)

So to prove it in the field case, it suffices to prove that this abstract norm map is given by a product of distinct embeddings in a closure (for separable extensions). For this, there is still some linear algebra that needs to be done, which I can give hints for if you're stuck.
